# unknown issue in my java method or with my maths?

Tags: java, swing, math, methods, jlabel

I have been building a game for the last six month using Java and hve come across a problem which I just cant resolve. Below is the best and closest attempt to perfect execution I have got, but it still has a problem.

In my game, a player can buy and sell items at a randomly set prices as he travels the world. When a purchase is made of any item, the quantity of that item gets recorded in the players window, whos total items can be gained through the method getItems2();.

A feature I would like to add is one that takes the players cash and calculates how many itrms a player can buy with his money. The problem I have is that when shipping these items to another country, this calculation has to consider that a shipping unit can only carry 10000 items and each one costs £700 and the maximum items a ship can carry is 1000000 items(100 units total - £70000). A player can carry items in his own pockets if he has <= 1000 items, anymore and he is forced to pay shipping fees. This calculation also has to consider that using method getItems2(); if a player is already carrying 100000 itrms, then he can only possibly carry 900000 more items if his cash allows him too.

My method below works to a point that I believe the number becomes to large for a long value to carry - I think?

If anybody could help me solve this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void getItems2(){
DopeWars.ec = DopeWars.pEcstacy.getText();
DopeWars.sp = DopeWars.pSpeed.getText();
DopeWars.ca = DopeWars.pCannabis.getText();
DopeWars.sh = DopeWars.pShrooms.getText();
DopeWars.co = DopeWars.pCocaine.getText();
DopeWars.he = DopeWars.pHeroin.getText();
DopeWars.cr = DopeWars.pCrack.getText();
DopeWars.md = DopeWars.pMdma.getText();
DopeWars.ls = DopeWars.pLsd.getText();

DopeWars.ecc = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.ec);
DopeWars.spp = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.sp);
DopeWars.caa = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.ca);
DopeWars.shh = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.sh);
DopeWars.coo = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.co);
DopeWars.hee = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.he);
DopeWars.crr = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.cr);
DopeWars.mdd = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.md);
DopeWars.lss = Long.parseLong(DopeWars.ls);

taken = DopeWars.ecc + DopeWars.spp + DopeWars.caa + DopeWars.shh + DopeWars.coo + DopeWars.hee + DopeWars.crr + DopeWars.mdd + DopeWars.lss;
return;
}

public static void EngPrice1(){
String aa = DopeWars.engEcsPrice.getText();
price = Long.parseLong(aa);
cash = playerCash + playerBank;
items = cash / price;

iCount();
if (i1 <= 0){
    DopeWars.m1.setText("0 Max");
}
if (i1 > 0){
    DopeWars.m1.setText(i1 + " Max");
}
}

public static void iCount(){
getItems2();
i = items + taken;

if (i <= 1000){
    cost = 50;
    items2 = cost / price;
    double items3 = items - items2;
    i1 = (long) items3;
    return;     
}
if (i > 1000){
    ///
    if (i >= 1000000){
        m1.setText("0 Max");
        return;
    }
    ///
    boxNo = 0;
    iCount2();
    return;
}
}

public static void iCount2(){

if (i <= 10000){        
    boxNo++;
    cost = boxNo * 700;
    items2 = cost / price;
    double items3 = items - items2;
    double vv = items3 * price;
    long vvv = (long) vv;
    if (cash - vvv < cost){
        items3 = items3 - 1;
    }       
    i1 = (long) items3;
    return; 
}
if (i > 10000){
    boxNo++;
    i = i - 10000;
    iCount2();
}
}
```

Comment: any reason for the down vote? I included source code, formatted it. Whats wrong with the question?

Comment: Don't know the reason of the down voter, but is your code [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: My code is as minimal as it could possibly be without missing anything that may be considered as important. In my opinion it is complete. And im not sure what you mean when u say "verifiable"- if you mean... can I verify that it works, yes. But that would involve uploading 1000s of lines of code(swing panels, labels and such), defeating the point of being minimal. Why, is there anything you have noticed needs being included? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Just read your link, there is no error message given, just a jlabel that all of a sudden stops printing text( my assumption is that the long data type cannot carry the number?). If there was a line that I thought gave the issue, I would say it might be the (double vv = items3 * price) line. But that would only be a guess.

Comment: If it helps, what I mean by too large to carry.....Before jlabel m1 gets printed with maximum number of items

Comment: `**Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still **produces the same problem**` - Your code does not produce the problem. Why? Because we can't run it. All it would produce in its current state are a million compile errors. Please post something we can copy-paste-compil-run, which should reproduce the problem. If you have to create a whole other program to demonstrate this, then please do. The more effort you  put into your question, the more likely it will get answered (in most cases :-)

Comment: In other words, if you have a problem with application logic, just create a small program that attempts to do the same thing the main application is trying to do, with the same logic. It should be a program that just demonstrate the same logical algorithm, and it does not have to be in any way related to your full application.

Comment: I will not try to create an entire set of classes just to test your small methods, please read what @peeskillet wrote. But if you don't have any exception and the label stops showing text, maybe the content is too long for the `width` of the label. But in this case you should see at least a `...` on the label.

Comment: This was something that I thought somebody would easily notice in my code or wrong with my maths. Clearly this is a view from somebody who knows whats needed what components and bits are too hand. Point taken, I will isolate the issue into a smaller easier program. Thanks.

Comment: I notice that you're writing far too much code.  All those values could be easily compressed into a single Map of key/value pairs.  Magic numbers everywhere.  Poor abstraction.  No wonder you're having problems.

Comment: A hint for minimal: skip the `Long.parseLong` steps.  Find some `long` values that make the error happen, and hard code them for us.  Print numbers to the console.  Do your numbers come out correctly on the console, but not on your `Label`?  Btw, a `long` can handle an 18 digit number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its kinda hard to explain how its worked, but by breaking the maths down and using if statements toto check if cash < or >  price * 100000, if not check if cash > or < price * 10000.... and so on until counting units. Doing it all in one repetitive method loop would cause a stackOverflow. Thanks for the help anyhow.